# AChartEngine will not display second series

Tags: android, achartengine

I have a chart in my Android app where I am using AChartEngine.  I am having an issue with the second series not showing on the XY graph.  I'm not seeing where I am going wrong with this.  I have confirmed that all of the series data is there.  The first series shows data over weeks.  The second series should be a vertical line at a specific week.  Here is the code:

```
    XYSeries seriesStat = new XYSeries("Standards");
    XYSeries seriesSelect = new XYSeries("Specific");
    for (dbBirdData bird : data)
    {
        seriesStat.add(bird.getage(), bird.getvalue());
        seriesSelect.add(age, bird.getvalue());
    }

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();    
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer2 = new XYSeriesRenderer();

    dataset.addSeries(seriesStat);                  
    renderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);


    dataset.addSeries(seriesSelect);        
    renderer2.setColor(Color.RED);      
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer2);


    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setChartTitle(title);
    mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);      
    mRenderer.setXTitle("Week");
    mRenderer.setYTitle("Standard Value");
    mRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
    mRenderer.setXAxisMin(17);
    mRenderer.setXAxisMax(90.0);    

    return ChartFactory.getLineChartView(context, dataset, mRenderer);
```

Any help would be awesome, and thank you in advanced!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not complete, but I think I know what the problem is with the vertical line series. You are probably adding multiple points having the same X value. This is not supported in AChartEngine. When you need to do this, just add very close numbers on the `X` axis, but not exactly the same. Example: `10, 10.000000001` and so on.